# Getting a Custom Elements using a Chrome Addon Content Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube

When I execute this code in the console of a website, it goes well, and reaches the `console.log('defined')`.
However, when I execute it via a chrome extension content script, I keep getting "undefined" in my customElements prints. Why?

```js
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://unpkg.com/pose-viewer@0.2.3/dist/pose-viewer/pose-viewer.esm.js');
document.body.appendChild(script);

while (!window.customElements.get('pose-viewer')) {
    await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))
    console.log(window.customElements.get('pose-viewer'))
}

console.log('defined')
```

I can see the script being injected to the page and loaded well via the network tab.
Additionally, if I run this through the chrome extension, and then try `window.customElements.get('pose-viewer')` in the console, it works.

Comment: If you altered `run_at` in your manifest.json the DOM may not be available and you'll have to wait for it https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time

Answer (score 1):

Load it via custom loader and inject to verify customelements

In Content Script

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL("js/customloader.js"));    
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

And the js/customloader.js

```js
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://unpkg.com/pose-viewer@0.2.3/dist/pose-viewer/pose-viewer.esm.js');
script.onload = function() {
    verifyCustomElements().then(fn => {
        console.log('defined')
        console.log(window.customElements)
    })
}
document.body.appendChild(script);


async function verifyCustomElements(){ 
    while (!window.customElements.get('pose-viewer')) {
        await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))
        consol.log("checking")
        console.log(window.customElements.get('pose-viewer'))
    } 
}
```

The defined now is ready to do customElements Stuff Now :)

Comment: I have done a small extension to test the behavior https://github.com/muthuishere/customloadscript

Answer (score 0):

Check if adding `tabs` to the list of permissions solves it.

Comment: Check the other permissions

Comment: I added all the premissions i could find and it still doesnt work